# "isomorphism" of spaces of functions in algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

What is the definition of "isomorphism" of spaces of functions in algebraic geometry?

I know what a morphism  is  but what is "isomorphism"?

Comment: It is hard to answer this question without knowing whether you are working with algebraic varieties or schemes. Also, what is meant by "space of functions"? Do you mean coordinate ring, structure sheaf, function field,...?

Comment: I am studying from the book  Görtz, Ulrich, Wedhorn, Torsten . He first defines a space of functions in general over a field k in general. Then goes to the varieties.

Comment: My question is that except the categorical  view in the following answer is there any other answer giving more details?

Answer (score 2):

An isomorphism is a morphism $f$ such that there is a morphism $g$ with $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ the identity morphism.

Comment: ... which works for *any* category and is not restricted to algebraic geometry.

Comment: there is no question about it